# materialize best practice validate empty field

Tags: html, validation, material-design, materialize

i use this form

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="email2" type="email" class="validate">
                <label for="email2" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="example" name="example" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                <label for="example" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Field</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

mail field is ok. if I post in an incorrect mail address error message appears.

example field not work. i would check if field is not empty and then show error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You forgot to add `required=""` and `aria-required="true"`
here is the completes snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="email2" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                <label for="email2" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="example" name="example" type="text" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
                <label for="example" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Field</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u76rdq2h/

Comment: He is doing as you say you enable the validation html5 and not that of the framework.

Comment: Sorry I cannot get your point clearly, you need to make "example input field" work on validate right? or you need more like this [https://jsfiddle.net/rz0zk5u6/14/](https://jsfiddle.net/rz0zk5u6/14/)

Comment: i need,as it happens for the email field, when example field lose focus validator sign it as wrong if empty. no external libraries. it's possible?

Comment: you need jquery to achieve that

Comment: The jsfiddle is using default html5 validation. How to get it by default.

Comment: The comment by @ichadr shows how validation would work for required fields with the materializecss.com library. That answer is great!

Answer (score 1):

comment to **ichadhr's** comment

/** FIXES for error messages */

```
label {
    width: 100%;
}
.input-field label:not(.active):after {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-140%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-140%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-140%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-140%);
    transform: translateY(-140%);
}
```